# Use Windows Azure CLI without publishsettings file?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to configure the Windows Azure CLI tools without using a .publishsettings file?   The 'azure account -h' command lists only options for downloading and importing a .publishsettings file.

Comment: I think it MIGHT be possible if you can set the storage account name and subscription ID, and import a management cert.  However, I'm having trouble importing the management cert.  I've created a bug at https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat/issues/277.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I could tell, which is a shame as it is possible in PowerShell (using `Set-AzureSubscription`)

Answer (score 0):

The current Version - Azure CLI 2 - can do that without any problems.
You have to use `az login` to provide your credentials and the you can use the cli, switching accounts etc.